# Operator == not compatible with type unit256 and address // TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call

Tags: solidity, truffle

I got 2 problem when i follow instruction. Here my contract file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./DappToken.sol";

contract DappTokenSale {
    address admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice; 
    }

    function multiply (uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens (uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require (msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require (tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require (tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }

    function endSale () public {
        require (msg.value == admin);
        require (tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
        selfdestruct(admin);
    }
}
```

and the cmd said:

[image]

How to fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first error, `msg.value` should be `msg.sender`. On the second error, you need to specify `address payable admin;` on declaration.

Comment: The both problem seem fixed, but I got another problem "Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?", do you know why ?

Comment: Without seeing the source for it, DappToken's `transfer()` method needs to return a Boolean value. If it doesn't, then the problem would be your require statement before `selfdestruct`. The ERC20 standard specifies that transfer should return a bool.